# What is the default `fill character` of std::stringstream?

Tags: c++, stringstream, clang++, libc++, setw

Is it implementation defined or standards suggest a default fill character for streams?

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

int main ()
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << std::setw( 10 ) << 25 << std::endl;

    std::cout << stream.str() << std::endl;
}
```

With `clang++ --stdlib=libstdc++`

```
$ clang++ --stdlib=libstdc++ test.cpp
$ ./a.out | hexdump
0000000 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 32 35 0a 0a
000000c
$
```

With `clang++ --stdlib=libc++`

```
$ clang++ --stdlib=libc++ test.cpp
$ ./a.out | hexdump
0000000 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 32 35 0a 0a
000000c
```

Version

```
$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

I was able to fix it with `std::setfill(' ')`, but am curious to know if it is a `clang` bug.

Comment: There is no 'libc++' on Fedora 19.  What is yours?

Comment: @rickhg12hs, I'm on mac. Not sure about linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default fill character for a stream `s` is `s.widen(' ')` according to 27.5.5.2 [basic.ios.cons] paragraph 3/Table 128. What character results  from `s.widen(' ')` is, however, dependent on the `std::locale` as `s.widen(c)` is (27.5.5.3 [basic.ios.members] paragraph 12):

```
std::use_facet<std::ctype<cT>>(s.getloc()).widen(c)
```

BTW, you should use `std::ostringstream` when you are only writing to the stream and there is [no use of `std::endl`](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/) ever.

Comment: Thanks. So it looks like a bug with implementation. `s.widen(' ')` with both `libstdc++` and `libc++` return `0x20`, which is not what fill char for stream is with `libc++`.

Comment: Looks like there already is a [bug filed](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17604) and fixed.